# .htaccess mod_rewrite remove .php extension, but preserve URL path

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have PHP scripts that work properly, being called like this:
www.example.com/user.php/paul
and
www.example.com/tag.php/food

I'm having trouble getting .htaccess to rewrite properly. I'm trying to achieve this:
www.example.com/user/paul
www.example.com/tag/food

So far, I can get it to redirect /user to /user.php, but the /paul is lost; breaking my script.

My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /([^.\ ]+\.)+php(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)*index/?$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^([^.]+\.)+([a-z0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1.php [L]
```

Please help.
Thanks!
Paul

Answer (score 1):

You probably should be using a rule like this somewhere:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /$1.php/$2
```

Here's it again, in English.

```
First comes the beginning of the path                        ^/
The first component of the path doesn't have / symbols in it [^/]*
We remember it                                               ()
Then comes the slash between the components                  /
Then the second component without the / symbols              [^/]*
Remember it too                                              ()
And the path ends                                            $
```

Replace it with the first remembered things followed by `.php/` followed by the second remembered thing.

You probably don't want to use `[L]` in this rule, the redirect is not necessary, the user doesn't need to know that your scripts really have a `.php` suffix.

Hope this is correct, I cannot check it on a working Apache right now.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# external redirect to hide .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.php/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

# internal redirect to add .php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?<!\.php)/(.*)$ /$1.php/$2 [L]
```

Comment: @Paul: May be you can give some details of what's not working. btw I have tested that answer on my Linux and Mac before posting.

Comment: It is the same issue as before: /user redirects properly to /user.php, but /user/paul gives a 404

Comment: That's weird since I tested it again on my Win7 installation and it worked again. Do you have any .htaccess inside `user/` folder as well? Can you paste your relevant error.log and access.log in your question?

Comment: There is no actual /user folder. 

[Wed Jun 08 20:15:38 2011] [error] [client XX.XX.XX.XX] File does not exist: /home/www.example.com/user

Comment: XX.XX.XX.XX - - [08/Jun/2011:20:15:37 -0700] "GET /user/paul/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1026 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.77 Safari/534.24"

Comment: Well that explains. If there is no actual folder `user/` then obviously `user/paul.php` doesn't exist and hence you get 404 error. Remember above code is only appending `.php` to a URI while hiding it externally.

Comment: Hmm ok i will take another shot at it. Do you want to support only `/tag` and `/user` or every `/whatever/foo` should be redirecting to `/whatever.php`?

Comment: @Paul: I have modified my answer based on my understanding, please try it now.